# ngForm inside a Carousel Slide in UI Bootstrap not working

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using the a Carousel for its effect of sliding, but I want to insert a form per slide, After inserting the ngForm, the $scope does not have the instance of that ngForm. If I place the ngForm outside of the Carousel, then the instance appear in the $scope. Example:

```
<data:carousel>
    <data:slide active="slides[0].active">
        <form name="formGI" data-ng-submit="SaveAndNext(cosvr.company)" novalidate>
            <div class="row-fluid text-center topSmallPad">
                <div class="span12">
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </data:slide>
</data:carousel>
```

the code above is not working, the $scope should have an instance: $scope.formGI. but, If place the form outside the Carousel like this:

```
<form name="formGI" data-ng-submit="SaveAndNext(cosvr.company)" novalidate>
    <data:carousel>
        <data:slide active="slides[0].active">
            <div class="row-fluid text-center topSmallPad">
                <div class="span12">
                </div>
            </div>
        </data:slide>
    </data:carousel>
</form>
```

Works correctly... any ideas?

Checkout the Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/XR03h5akcu3IWXJwu7KW

and is happening in Accordions too!

Answer (score 2):

If anybody is interested, I made a home made clone/modification of Carousel/Slide, called FormCarousel/FormSlide.

Here is the plunker with the code and a working example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/JReSqUJQrTx3zQKROtww

Check the console of your browser to see the object.

Feel free to modify it, make more friendly if you want... but, please share it.

The structure must be:

```
<form-carousel>
    <form-slide active="forms[0].active" form_object="forms[0].form" form_name="frmMain">
        <form name="frmMain"></form>
    </form-slide>
</form-carousel>
```

So is working beautifully for me... hope may help someone else.

_e